# how to map same class with different table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy use `__tablename__` to map a class and a database table name. However, in my case, there are maybe more than 20 tables. The only difference between them is table name, so I want to reuse the same class `CommonTable` to map different table names. is there any way to do it?

Comment: (Just trying to understand the case): After you have done that, when you would like to query for that Class, shall it search it all the tables or just a specific one? The same goes in case you wish to insert a new record: how would you like to specify which table will the row be inserted into? What is the difference between those 20 tables?

Comment: because there will waste too much time if  all records saved in the same table

Comment: I am sorry, but I am even more lost than before...

Comment: @van I have exactly the same question here. What talking about is basically sharding. I don't think there's any good way to achieve this in sqlalchemy.

Comment: @user1685095: Take a look at `Alternative-2` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704470/mapping-lots-of-similar-tables-in-sqlalchemy/22825638#22825638) question/answer. Basically, one could map them using [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://docs2.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/inheritance.html#concrete-table-inheritance)

Comment: @van It suffers from exactly the same problem all answers on that question suffer. It creates class for every table. Which is very inefficient if you think about it. All you need is to produce ```select from some_table``` "from" clause dynamically, effectively changing one part of one word. And for that sqlalchemy offers creating a bunch of classes, that aren't models. That's pretty stupid.

Comment: @user1685095: does not look like we are going to have a constructive conversation here. Hope you find a good solution, and please share once you do. Thank you.

Comment: @user1685095: there was a feature `entity_name` in old releases. This was [removed](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_05.html#removed) in 0.5. See also the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/niOgZBqIuW0) and this [recipe](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/EntityName). As you know (and as mentioned in @van's answer) standard solutions to such problems are partitioning (DB solves your problem, transparent to SQLAlchemy), sharding (multiple DBs, supported by SQLAlchemy), and creating multiple classes.