# Mapping lots of similar tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have many (~2000) locations with time series data. Each time series has millions of rows. I would like to store these in a Postgres database. My current approach is to have a table for each location time series, and a meta table which stores information about each location (coordinates, elevation etc). I am using Python/SQLAlchemy to create and populate the tables. I would like to have a relationship between the meta table and each time series table to do queries like "select all locations that have data between date A and date B" and "select all data for date A and export a csv with coordinates". What is the best way to create many tables with the same structure (only the name is different) and have a relationship with a meta table? Or should I use a different database design?

Currently I am using this type of approach to generate a lot of similar mappings:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.types import Float, String, DateTime, Integer
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref

Base = declarative_base()


def make_timeseries(name):
    class TimeSeries(Base):

        __tablename__ = name
        table_name = Column(String(50), ForeignKey('locations.table_name'))
        datetime = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
        value = Column(Float)

        location = relationship('Location', backref=backref('timeseries',
                                lazy='dynamic'))

        def __init__(self, table_name, datetime, value):
            self.table_name = table_name
            self.datetime = datetime
            self.value = value

        def __repr__(self):
            return "{}: {}".format(self.datetime, self.value)

    return TimeSeries


class Location(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'locations'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    lon = Column(Float)
    lat = Column(Float)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection_string = 'postgresql://user:pw@localhost/location_test'
    engine = create_engine(connection_string)
    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    TS1 = make_timeseries('ts1')
    # TS2 = make_timeseries('ts2')   # this breaks because of the foreign key
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session.add(TS1("ts1", "2001-01-01", 999))
    session.add(TS1("ts1", "2001-01-02", -555))

    qs = session.query(Location).first()
    print qs.timeseries.all()
```

This approach has some problems, most notably that if I create more than one `TimeSeries` the foreign key doesn't work. Previously I've used some work arounds, but it all seems like a big hack and I feel that there must be a better way of doing this. How should I organise and access my data?

Answer (score 14):

## `Alternative-1: Table Partitioning`

`Partitioning` immediately comes to mind as soon as I read **exactly** the same table structure. I am not a DBA, and do not have much production experience using it (even more so on PostgreSQL), but 
please read [`PostgreSQL - Partitioning`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html) documentation. Table partitioning seeks to solve exactly the problem you have, but over 1K tables/partitions sounds challenging; therefore please do more research on forums/SO for scalability related questions on this topic.

Given that both of your mostly used search criterias, `datetime` component is very important, therefore there must be solid indexing strategy on it. If you decide to go with **`partitioning`** root, the obvious partitioning strategy would be based on date ranges. This might allow you to partition older data in different chunks compared to most recent data, especially assuming that old data is (almost never) updated, so physical layouts would be dense and efficient; while you could employ another strategy for more "recent" data.

## `Alternative-2: trick SQLAlchemy`

This basically makes your sample code work by tricking SA to assume that all those `TimeSeries` are `children` of one entity using [`Concrete Table Inheritance`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html#concrete-table-inheritance). The code below is self-contained and creates 50 table with minimum data in it. But if you have a database already, it should allow you to check the performance rather quickly, so that you can make a decision if it is even a close possibility.

```
from datetime import date, datetime

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, DateTime, Float, ForeignKey, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, configure_mappers, joinedload
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import AbstractConcreteBase, ConcreteBase


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base(engine)


# MODEL
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    lon = Column(Float)
    lat = Column(Float)


class TSBase(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    @declared_attr
    def table_name(cls):
        return Column(String(50), ForeignKey('locations.table_name'))


def make_timeseries(name):
    class TimeSeries(TSBase):
        __tablename__ = name
        __mapper_args__ = { 'polymorphic_identity': name, 'concrete':True}

        datetime = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
        value = Column(Float)

        def __init__(self, datetime, value, table_name=name ):
            self.table_name = table_name
            self.datetime = datetime
            self.value = value

    return TimeSeries


def _test_model():
    _NUM = 50
    # 0. generate classes for all tables
    TS_list = [make_timeseries('ts{}'.format(1+i)) for i in range(_NUM)]
    TS1, TS2, TS3 = TS_list[:3] # just to have some named ones
    Base.metadata.create_all()
    print('-'*80)

    # 1. configure mappers
    configure_mappers()

    # 2. define relationship
    Location.timeseries = relationship(TSBase, lazy="dynamic")
    print('-'*80)

    # 3. add some test data
    session.add_all([Location(table_name='ts{}'.format(1+i), lat=5+i, lon=1+i*2)
        for i in range(_NUM)])
    session.commit()
    print('-'*80)

    session.add(TS1(datetime(2001,1,1,3), 999))
    session.add(TS1(datetime(2001,1,2,2), 1))
    session.add(TS2(datetime(2001,1,2,8), 33))
    session.add(TS2(datetime(2002,1,2,18,50), -555))
    session.add(TS3(datetime(2005,1,3,3,33), 8))
    session.commit()


    # Query-1: get all timeseries of one Location
    #qs = session.query(Location).first()
    qs = session.query(Location).filter(Location.table_name == "ts1").first()
    print(qs)
    print(qs.timeseries.all())
    assert 2 == len(qs.timeseries.all())
    print('-'*80)


    # Query-2: select all location with data between date-A and date-B
    dateA, dateB = date(2001,1,1), date(2003,12,31)
    qs = (session.query(Location)
            .join(TSBase, Location.timeseries)
            .filter(TSBase.datetime >= dateA)
            .filter(TSBase.datetime <= dateB)
            ).all()
    print(qs)
    assert 2 == len(qs)
    print('-'*80)


    # Query-3: select all data (including coordinates) for date A
    dateA = date(2001,1,1)
    qs = (session.query(Location.lat, Location.lon, TSBase.datetime, TSBase.value)
            .join(TSBase, Location.timeseries)
            .filter(func.date(TSBase.datetime) == dateA)
            ).all()
    print(qs)
    # @note: qs is list of tuples; easy export to CSV
    assert 1 == len(qs)
    print('-'*80)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _test_model()
```

## `Alternative-3: a-la BigData`

If you do get into performance problems using database, I would probably try:

- still keep the data in separate tables/databases/schemas like you do right now
- bulk-import data using "native" solutions provided by your database engine
- use [`MapReduce`-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) analysis.

  - Here I would stay with python and sqlalchemy and implemnent own distributed query and aggregation (or find something existing). This, obviously, only works if you do not have requirement to produce those results directly on the database.

## *edit-1:* `Alternative-4: TimeSeries databases`

I have no experience using those on a large scale, but definitely an option worth considering.

---

*Would be fantastic if you could later share your findings and whole decision-making process on this.*

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll check out the first two alternatives initially and see how that goes. I think (or at least hope) a "Big Data" solution is overkill here as the data set is big, but not "Big Data". Some good information here, gives me plenty to work with.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid the database design you mention above. I don't know enough about the data you are working with, but it sounds like you should have two tables. One table for location, and a child table for location_data. The location table would store the data you mention above such as coordinates and elevations. The location_data table would store the location_id from the location table as well as the time series data you want to track.

This would eliminate changing db structure and code changes every time you add another location, and would allow the types of queries you are looking at doing.

Answer (score 3):

Two parts:

## only use two tables

there's no need to have dozens or hundreds of identical tables.  just have a table for `location` and one for `location_data` , where every entry will fkey onto location.  also create an index on the location_data table for the location_id, so you have efficient searching.

## don't use sqlalchemy to create this

i love sqlalchemy. i use it every day.  it's great for managing your database and adding some rows, but you don't want to use it for initial setup that has millions of rows.  you want to generate a file that is compatible with postgres' "COPY" statement [ http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html ]  COPY will let you pull in a ton of data fast; it's what is used during dump/restore operations.

sqlalchemy will be great for querying this and adding rows as they come in.  if you have bulk operations, you should use COPY.

Comment: +1 for the COPY advice. An import from CSV (COPY FROM) will also work great

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So as long as I have the index, querying should be fast even if there are billions of rows? Is there anything else needed besides that and the foreign key? I have realised that `COPY` is the way to go for getting the data in, would take (close to) forever otherwise.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to take my "Two Tables" advice back. I didn't realize you were dealing with Billions; I thought you only had Millions.  Postgres doesn't perform too well at the billions range -- once you hit 1B, people often try to partition the data, and your original approach is essentially a partition based on location.  

I thought about running a script to generate your classes, but 2k tables is huge.  The dynamic approach does seem the right direction. I'd suggest asking this on the SqlALchemy list.  I'm sure Mike will have some good advice on how to generate the classes dynamically.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've been thinking of writing a script that outputs a python file with the 2k mapped classes in it, but again - feels very hacky. I'll ask on the mailing list - thanks!