# SQLAlchemy, using the same model with multiple tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have data for a particular entity partitioned across multiple identical tables, often separated chronologically or by numeric range. For instance, I may have a table called mytable for current data, a mytable_2013 for last year's data, mytable_2012, and so on.

Only the current table is ever written to. The others are only consulted. With SQLAlchemy, is there any way I can specify the table to query from when using the declarative model?

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22825638/99594 in the `Concrete Table Inheritance` section. I would not like to re-post it as an answer, as it is quite long. In your case you can query `MyTable` only when working with the current data, and do a `polymorphic` search when looking for all the history.

Comment: Thanks. My case is more simple it's the same entity distributed horizontally, not multiple entities defined by inheritance. Considering that, it seems to be the same solution as the one by @viktor.likin answer below.

Comment: Inheritance is just a trick to get SA to query across multiple tables. But if you do not need that, viktor's solution is perfect. Note that if you have foreign keys from your table(s), you will need to use `declared_attr`

Comment: Yeah, I just stumbled on that. Can you clarify the point about inheritance being just a trick to get SA to query across multiple tables. Does that work with the horizontal partitioning I'm doing? SQLAlchemy does an UNION automatically?

Comment: Yes, it can work with the horizontal partitioning you are doing. The trick is to query all (or some of) the (fake) inheritance tree `polymorphically`. This is to say: if you make SA think that all those tables are "children" of `MyBaseTable`, and you execute a query polymorphically, SA will fetch data from all these tables (`mytable`, `mytable_2012`, etc) automatically for you. Indeed, SA does a `UNION` automatically.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I wanted. Can you post an answer with your first comment so I can award you the bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*As requested, re-posting as answer:*

Please take a look at this answer to [Mapping lots of similar tables in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22825638/99594) in the `Concrete Table Inheritance` section.
In your case you can query `MyTable` only when working with the current data, and do a polymorphic search on all tables when you need the whole history.

Answer (score 10):

Use mixins and change table names by an object property.

```
class Node(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'node'
  nid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  uuid = Column(String(128))
  vid = Column(Integer)

class Node1(Node):
  __tablename__ = 'node_1'

class Node2(Node):
  __tablename__ = 'node_2'
```

Comment: This method is less complicated than the accepted answer. Here is a link to a recipe that uses a similar approach: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/EntityName

Comment: not working anymore, produces `NoForeignKeysError("Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'Node and 'Node1'.",)`

Comment: The answer is correct, the code is not (or not anymore ;-)). Define the mixin by a) replicating the `Node`-class as `class NodeMixin(object):` followed by the column definitions of the `Node`-class **but without** the `__table_name__`-property and b) for `Node1` and `Node2` inherit from the mixin and `Base`, e. g. `class Node1(NodeMixin, Base): __tablename__ = "node_1"`. See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html?highlight=mixin#mixing-in-columns